# Flutter release build crashes instantly without any errors logged (iOS)

Tags: xcode, flutter, flutter-ios

I am not totally sure how to reproduce this issue as I do not know what causes this issue. I currently have an app that is working in debug mode and profile mode, but I am unable to build it for release mode. I am installing it directly via cable to a physical iPhone (not an emulator) that is running iOS 14.8. I do not own an Android device, so I am unsure if this issue happens for Android builds too. I have tried removing my Pods folder, Podfile, Podfile.lock updating Cocoapods, and running `flutter clean` but the issue persists. I created a new flutter project from a provided template and have the same issue: I can build in debug mode and profile mode but not release mode. The log file below is for the barebones project as it has less clutter.

Flutter doctor output:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.2, on macOS 11.4 20F71 darwin-x64, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 3.0.2 at /Users/aaron/development/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision cd41fdd495 (8 days ago), 2022-06-08 09:52:13 -0700
    • Engine revision f15f824b57
    • Dart version 2.17.3
    • DevTools version 2.12.2

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/aaron/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-18.0.1.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 18.0.1.1+2-6)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.2.1)
    • Xcode at /Users/aaron/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✗] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.

[!] Android Studio (not installed)
    • Android Studio not found; download from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup for detailed instructions).

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • אהרן iPhone (mobile) • 00008020-001A74AA01F9002E            • ios        • iOS 14.8 18H17
    • iPhone 13 (mobile)   • DBEAE20E-D3D1-43B5-BC15-CC8D20753EEB • ios        • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-15-2 (simulator)
    • macOS (desktop)      • macos                                • darwin-x64 • macOS 11.4 20F71 darwin-x64

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

Here is my build log (`flutter run --release --verbose`)

https://pastebin.com/f4QD1tXU

If you navigate to the end, you can see that it successfully deploys to my device. What is not reflected in the logs is that upon launching there is a brief white screen and the app crashes. At this point, I hit 'q' to end the terminal session and 'Application finished' Is logged. No errors or exceptions are logged when the app crashes, which makes me clueless on how to pinpoint the issue. Just to reiterate, the app can be installed and used without issue in debug mode and profile mode. It is only in release mode where this happens.

I wish I could provide more information, but I do not know where to begin fixing this.

Edit:

I noticed this in Xcode which I hadn't noticed before.

```
2022-06-16 15:32:44.889467-0500 Runner[68916:5583414] Metal API Validation Enabled
2022-06-16 15:32:45.053915-0500 Runner[68916:5583414] [VERBOSE-3:dart_vm_initializer.cc(22)] Error while initializing the Dart VM: Flag dedup_instructions is false in snapshot, but dedup_instructions is always true in product mode
```

Running a profile or debug build in Xcode works without this error. Perhaps this is the root cause in release mode. Still seeking answers on how to resolve this.

Comment: Have you gotten any solution for this?

Comment: @mr5 I did not find a fix for this. I was using a borrowed computer from my university and no longer faced the issue when using a different device.

Answer (score 2):

This can happen if you are using firebase and is not configured properly. Or ads without Id in info plist

Comment: I do not use Ads, but I have firebase in my main project. Even with that though, there is no firebase in the default project where this issue also occurs.

Comment: Does this happen in default projects too? If you create an empty flutter project

Comment: Yes, it still happens in default / empty projects with no packages

Comment: Hope you are aware that it will work only if the device is connected to the machine. The moment you disconnect the app will close automatically. Please try uploading the build in test flight and check once